# How to maintain order of subscribers with async operations

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an angular component which subscribes to its route params. Whenever the route params change, it reads the `id` from the params and calls a function to look up the record for that id. The function returns a promise. Upon resolving, the component sets a property on itself for the purposes of databinding.

In some cases, it seems that the responses are getting out of order, and the wrong value is set. Here's what it looks like:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
    const id = params['id'];
    console.log('processing', id);
    this.service.getPerson(id).then((person) => {
      console.log('processed id', id);
      this.person = person; // sometimes this happens out of order
    }
  }
}
```

So, let's say I have a textbox where I filter by name, and as I type, navigation events occur where `id` gets the first result for that name. Sometimes I see this:

> processing 1
>
> processing 2
>
> processed 2
>
> processed 1   <---- PROBLEM

What is the most elegant way to solve this? I have considered converting the promise to an observable and trying to cancel it, but that seems heavy-handed. I am trying to figure out if there's a way to serialize subscriptions, so that the second 'processing' doens't begin until the first one completes.

Comment: You can probably use a `concatMap` in a pipe to make sure that you process those page requests in order. However, do you really care about the prior request if a new one comes in before the last was done? Usually you wouldn't and should instead use `switchMap`.

Comment: `this.route.params.pipe(switchMap(params => this.service.getPerson(params['id']).then(person => this.person = person)))`

Comment: Correct, I would not care about the intermediate values. I will check out switchmap and get back to you. 

I am currently reading through all the operators. For the sake of completeness, `debounceTime` also does mitigate this situation as long as I can predict the maximum time that my `getPerson` will take. But that's not great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to make use of either [`concatMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html) or [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html). `concatMap` will make sure the previous request is finished processing before doing the next one. `switchMap` will also ensure the order, except it will abort the processing of the prior request if it is still processing when the next request comes in.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.pipe(
      map(params => params['id']),
      tap(id => console.log('processing', id)),
      concatMap(id => fromPromise(this.service.getPerson(id)).pipe(
        tap(person => console.log('processed id', id))
      )), 
      tap(person => this.person = person)
  )
  .subscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a 'request id' to each call, that gets returned back to you. Then in the callback you can check if the req id is higher than the last one you processed.

It's not ideal for little calls with single-integer responses, but I hid mine in the headers and used an interceptor/filter to echo that header back to the client on every request.